# access convert to sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

how can i convert this access statement to sql  ?

```
DELETE [Find duplicates for tBDEDom].* FROM [Find duplicates for tBDEDom];
```

Comment: What is `"Find duplicates for tBDEDom"`?

Comment: I don't know  ms-access exactly . I trying to convert

Comment: `[Find duplicates for tBDEDom]` here is a generated earlier query, which returns duplicates of rows. Such queries generate by Access wizard. So you need to to create a similar query in SQL and use it for deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tBDEDom( Id int, Name VARCHAR(10))

insert into #tBDEDom values(1, 'abc')
insert into #tBDEDom values(2, 'mpo')
insert into #tBDEDom values(3, 'atc')
insert into #tBDEDom values(4, 'xyz')
insert into #tBDEDom values(5, 'abc')
insert into #tBDEDom values(6, 'xyz')
insert into #tBDEDom values(7, 'abc')

SELECT * FROM #tBDEDom

;with cte
AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by Name order by Name) AS [rank] FROM #tBDEDom
)

DELETE FROM cte where [rank]>1

SELECT * FROM #tBDEDom

DROP TABLE #tBDEDom
```